# Change RDS to Public accessible

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-rds

I am a newbie in amazon web services and have got some questions related to amazon RDS:

1.How can we use AWS API to define an RDS and send the parameter 'publicly accessible' to it? I know that the CLI has a -pub flag ([CLI-RDS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/CommandLineReference/CLIReference-cmd-CreateDBInstance.html)) which can be used, but what about when we are not using CLI and gonna use some programming language like Node.js?

2.Is it possible to change the state of publicly-accessible parameter of an RDS? I mean If we have already defined an RDS in private state, can we change it later? If yes How? I also read the discussion here ([RDS to public](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=729693)), and they offered to Delete the current RDS & create final snapshot and then Restore the Snapshot with the the public availability zone. It's not possible in my case. Is there any other way? we want to change the state of publicly accessible parameter dynamically because of some security issues.

Comment: To do what you want in (2), it might be best to set up it in a public default situation, and then use a Network Access Control List to restrict public access as and when yuo want.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Actually we are monitoring some existing RDS and your solution is not applicable for us :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This API call is available on all clients (Console, SDK, CLI, ...) here is the documentation for node.js, check the `PubliclyAccessible` parameter:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/RDS.html#modifyDBInstance-property
2. It is surely possible. However, as the cloudformation documentation mentions, that requires substitution and so expect and plan for some downtime:
   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html#cfn-rds-dbinstance-publiclyaccessible

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I need. Thanks again :*